# Как сделать update записи после ее выборки SQL

Tags: sql

Например есть такой запрос

```
SELECT id FROM order WHERE id > 10
```

Возможно ли сделать в одном запросе сразу и UPDATE этой выбранной записи?
`UPDATE order SET count_view = count_view + 1` Суть заключается в том что-бы сделать счетчик просмотров. Хотелось бы оптимизировать все в один запрос

Comment: что за sql? ms , my?

Comment: mysql - в данном случае

Comment: в одном не получится, но если хочется сделать в одном обращении к базе используй хранимые процедуры

Comment: Как использовать эти процедуры? можно пример?

Comment: Мне нужно что-бы эта процедура вернула результат по которому я сделаю UPDATE правильно?

Comment: что значить использовать? как их вызвать в java могу дать пример. да правильно. в хранимке будет update и select, который и вернёт результат

Comment: @modelfak вы попробовали запрос в моем ответе?

Comment: @lolbas он не возвращает ничего

Comment: @Вадим если вы про мой запрос, то с чего бы он должен что-то возвращать? В вопросе ничего не сказано о возврате каких-либо значений

Comment: @ lolbas "Возможно ли сделать в одном запросе сразу и UPDATE этой выбранной записи?"  однозначно говорит о необходимости возврата

Comment: @Вадим хех, точно. В таком случае да, в один запрос нельзя

Comment: А вообще-то странный счетчик просмотров, почему не id = ? или я не догоняю чего-то :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
UPDATE order 
SET count_view = count_view + 1 
WHERE id in 
    (SELECT id FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM order) AS t
     WHERE t.id > 10)
```

Comment: надо не просто сделать update, а получить на выходе id...

Comment: @Вадим такого условия нет. В моем понимании `SELECT id ...` нужен только для `UPDATE` запроса

Comment: UPDATE order 
SET count_view = count_view + 1 
WHERE id > 10

Comment: в одном запросе обновить значение и получить обновленное значение нельзя